# Centos: Clamd and Razor-agents dependency failure on yum update when EPEL is enabled

Tags: centos, yum, gitlab, epel, rpm

I want to install Gitlab 6 to my CentOS 6.4 x64 server. I'm following the tutorial and enable EPEL with this command:

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

Then when I check my repolist, here's the result:

```
yum repolist
repo id           repo name                                               status
base              CentOS-6 - Base                                         6381
epel              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64          9893
extras            CentOS-6 - Extras                                         13
rpmforge          RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                             4643
updates           CentOS-6 - Updates                                      1484
repolist: 22414
```

After that, I go with `yum -y update` as it was said in the installation guide. However, I get errors on two packages: `amavisd-new-2.8.0-4.el6.noarch (epel)` and `razor-agents-2.85-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (@rpmforge)`. When I disabled EPEL and installed Gitlab, I couldn't manage to make it run. So I want to make sure to do everything as it was mentioned in the guide.

Here are the errors that I get.

```
yum -y update
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: amavisd-new-2.8.0-4.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: /etc/clamd.d
           Available: clamd-0.98-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               Not found
           Installed: clamd-0.98-2.el6.rf.x86_64 (@rpmforge)
               Not found
           Available: clamd-0.96.4-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Not found
           Available: clamd-0.96.5-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Not found
           Available: clamd-0.97-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Not found
           Available: clamd-0.97.1-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Not found
           Available: clamd-0.97.2-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Not found
           Available: clamd-0.97.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Not found
           Available: clamd-0.97.4-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Not found
           Available: clamd-0.97.5-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Not found
           Available: clamd-0.97.5-2.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Not found
           Available: clamd-0.97.6-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Not found
           Available: clamd-0.97.7-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Not found
           Available: clamd-0.98-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               Not found
Error: Package: razor-agents-2.85-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (@rpmforge)
           Requires: perl-Razor-Agent = 2.85-1.el6.rf
           Removing: perl-Razor-Agent-2.85-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (@rpmforge)
               perl-Razor-Agent = 2.85-1.el6.rf
           Updated By: perl-Razor-Agent-2.85-6.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               perl-Razor-Agent = 2.85-6.el6
           Available: perl-Razor-Agent-2.84-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               perl-Razor-Agent = 2.84-1.el6.rf
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I install these two packages without these errors? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into the same problems. As you have as well, I have the "epel" and the "rpmforge" repository installed.

As it seems the "epel" repository has some problem with the "amavisd-new" package that causes this problem. As the "amavisd-new" package is available as well in the "rpmforge" repository, you can install it from there. (same version as far as i could see)

You can simply disable the epel repository for the installation of amavisd-new via a command line parameter.

**yum --disablerepo=epel install amavisd-new**

When you do this you might notice another precondition error message about the "lzop" package. This package is only in the "epel" repository. So install first the "lzop" package and then install "amavisd-new" with the "epel" repository disabled. That solved it for me.

Comment: If you run the "yum --disablerepo=epel" install amavisd-new you might then run into troubles while updating via "yum update". The update causes then dependancy issues as the epel and the rpmforge have both the package in different versions. -- To solve that use the yum-plugin-priorities and configure lower priority for the epel repository as for the rpmforge repo. That way the update works without any additional hacks.

Answer (score 1):

razor-agents package is available in atrpms repository. The following commands are for i386. For x86_64 change i386 in the URL with x86_64.

wget http://dl.atrpms.net/el6-i386/atrpms/stable/atrpms-repo-6-7.el6.i686.rpm

rpm -Uvh atrpms-repo*rpm

yum install razor-agents